# Filtrar array y agregar una propiedad

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array `listadoAvances` donde se encuentran los avances de varios proyectos por periodo.

El periodo vigente: 06/21/2018 o en segundos 1529539200, tiene información de los 3 proyectos: proyecto 20, 21 y 22.

En el otro periodo: 06/14/2018, una semana antes exactamente, solo hay información de dos proyectos el 20 y 21. Porque el 22 aun no existía.

```
  listadoAvances = [
    // periodo vigente 06/21/2018
    {
      proyecto: 20, 
      timestamp: 1529539200, // segundos
      vigente: true,
      avance: 90
    },
    {
      proyecto: 21, 
      timestamp: 1529539200,
      vigente: true,
      avance: 70
    },
    {
      proyecto: 22,
      timestamp: 1529539200,
      vigente: true,
      avance: 100
    },
    // periodo 06/14/2018
    {
      proyecto: 20, 
      timestamp: 1528934400, // 1 semana antes de vigente (1529539200 - 604800)
      vigente: false,
      avance: 80
    },
    {
      proyecto: 21, 
      timestamp: 1528934400,
      vigente: false,
      avance: 50
    }  
  ]
```

Lo que necesito es obtener un listado de solo los proyectos vigentes, pero que incluya una nueva propiedad `incremento`, que es igual a la diferencia entre el avance vigente y el de la semana anterior del proyecto correspondiente.

Por ejemplo:

```
  listadoAvancesVigente = [
    {
      proyecto: 20, 
      timestamp: 1529539200,
      vigente: true,
      avance: 90,
      incremento: 10 // diferencia entre avance vigente y el de la semana anterior
    },
    {
      proyecto: 21, 
      timestamp: 1529539200,
      vigente: true,
      avance: 70,
      incremento: 20
    },
    {
      proyecto: 22,
      timestamp: 1529539200,
      vigente: true,
      avance: 100,
      incremento: 0 // no existia en la semana anterior, de forma que no hubo incremento.
    }
  ]
```

Filtrar los proyectos vigente me parece sencillo,

```
  listadoAvances.filter(p => {
    return p.vigente === true
  })
```

Sin embargo, no tengo claro como podría agregar la propiedad `incremento` de acuerdo a mi requerimiento.

Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 0):

intenta con este código:

```js
listadoAvances = [
  // periodo vigente 06/21/2018
  {
    proyecto: 20, 
    timestamp: 1529539200, // segundos
    vigente: true,
    avance: 90
  },
  {
    proyecto: 21, 
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    vigente: true,
    avance: 70
  },
  {
    proyecto: 22,
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    vigente: true,
    avance: 100
  },
  // periodo 06/14/2018
  {
    proyecto: 20, 
    timestamp: 1528934400, // 1 semana antes de vigente (1529539200 - 604800)
    vigente: false,
    avance: 80
  },
  {
    proyecto: 21, 
    timestamp: 1528934400,
    vigente: false,
    avance: 50
  }  
]
/* listadoAvancesVigente = [
  {
    proyecto: 20, 
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    vigente: true,
    avance: 90,
    incremento: 10 // diferencia entre avance vigente y el de la semana anterior
  },
  {
    proyecto: 21, 
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    vigente: true,
    avance: 70,
    incremento: 20
  },
  {
    proyecto: 22,
    timestamp: 1529539200,
    vigente: true,
    avance: 100,
    incremento: 0 // no existia en la semana anterior, de forma que no hubo incremento.
  }
] */
const proyectosAnteriores = listadoAvances.filter(p => p.timestamp === 1528934400)
const proyectosVigentes = listadoAvances.filter(p => p.vigente === true)

proyectosVigentes.forEach((p,i) => {
  const pa = proyectosAnteriores[i]
  if(pa === undefined){
    p.incremento = 0
  }else{
    p.incremento = p.avance - pa.avance
  }
  console.log(p)
});
```